How to mathematically model Bid and Ask as two separate processes, and combine into a Price process?
Let's say you were modeling bid and ask as two separate processes.
With their own mean and variance. And with the constraint that ask must be greater than or equal to bid.
How would you then mathematically derive price from this? Are there existing formulas or models or theories related to this?
That is, deriving the price process as something like a child process or dependent process. With bid and ask processes as the parent processes.
Sorry if I used inaccurate terms, I'm not sure about the exact terminology to use.

Hi: I haven't heard of anyone trying to do what you're thinking of so that may be why there are no responses ?

OK thank you for the comment :) I was thinking there might be some literature on this idea, as it relates to price discovery and market microstructure. But maybe there's nothing like that. Thank you for letting me know.

Hi Tristan: you should check out some of joel hasbrouck's material. He's written about market microstructure and I think he has a text. But I don't know if he has investigated what you mentioned. He's a faculty member at NYU so maybe check his website.

Great thank you for the suggestion.
